# How to add a specific word next to the finding word in a text file using Shell Script?

Tags: bash, shell

I tried to read a specific word (Apple) in a text file and I need to add a specific word (Samsung) next to the find word (Apple) using shell script.

I know how to read the file using the shell script and find a specific word.

```
#!/bin/bash

LOGFILE =$1

if[-f $LOGFILE ];
then
awk '/Apple/'
else 
echo "$LOGFILE not found "
fi
```

I need to know how to add new word next the finding word in same file.

example

The company **Apple** was founded on April 1, 1976, and incorporated as **Apple** Computer, Inc. on January 3, 1977.The word "Computer" was removed from its name Apple on January 9, 2007, the same day Steve Jobs introduced the iPhone, reflecting its shifted focus towards consumer electronics.

expected

The company **Apple** ***Samsung*** was founded on April 1, 1976, and incorporated as Apple Computer, Inc. on January 3, 1977.The word "Computer" was removed from its name **Apple** ***Samsung*** on January 9, 2007, the same day Steve Jobs introduced the iPhone, reflecting its shifted focus towards consumer electronics.

Thanks.

Comment: Your Bash syntax is invalid. Have you actually run the posted script?

Comment: @  CodeGnome well what wrong with #!/bin/bash? if i'm wrong let me correct

Comment: Why is "Apple Computer" not changed to "Apple Samsung Computer"?

Comment: @Bohemian Neither his code nor his corpus is valid. The underlying question itself is reasonable enough, but will probably be closed for violating SSCCE.

Comment: The `if` line needs spaces around the `[`; it is a command in its own right and, just as you can't write `catme` to run `cat` on a file `me`, you can't combine `if[-f` like that — the shell will look for a command called `if[-f` and will fail to find it.  You must write `if [ -f "$LOGFILE" ]` (the `]` is the last argument of the `[` command).  The chances are that there is a binary `/bin/[` or `/usr/bin/[` on your machine — though the shell doesn't execute that but uses a built-in version.  (Version 7 Unix shells did execute `/bin/[`!)

Answer (score 3):

Just use `sed`:

```
sed -i 's/Apple /& Samsung /g' myfile.txt
```

The `-i` flag (in-place) writes the output back to the file which will *overwrite* the source file.

`&` in the replacement means "entire match".

Comment: Well thanks it working fine but it didnt write in the myFile.txt. it print in the file in terminal

Comment: More concise would be `sed 's/Apple/& Samsung/g'`, and you probably still want to pipe through *fmt* or *fold* afterwards.

Comment: @stacktome Consider [accepting the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if it worked for you.  You might also want to refer to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 2):

### Substitute Text with Parameter Expansions

First of all, your Bash syntax is broken. Your script will not run as written.

Secondly, if you want to do this strictly in the shell, you should use a [shell parameter expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) to perform the substitutions, and the *fmt* command to re-flow the paragraphs afterwards. For example:

```
#!/bin/bash

LOGFILE="$1"

if [[ -r "$LOGFILE" ]]; then
    while read; do
      echo "${REPLY//Apple/Apple Samsung}"
    done < "$LOGFILE" | fmt
else
  echo "Error: $LOGFILE not readable" > /dev/stderr
  exit 66
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sed 's/Apple/& Samsung/g' $LOGFILE
```